# How to make a simple tab system without jquery UI

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I'm trying to make a simple tab system.. but the code only works for the first click and then stops responding.

I didn't want to go with jquery ui, as the file size is rather hefty.

```
$("#container1").hide();


if ($("#container1").is(":visible")) {
    $("#link1").click(function () {
        $("#container1").hide();
        $("#container2").show();
    });
};

if ($("#container2").is(":visible")) {
    $("#link2").click(function () {
        $("#container1").show();
        $("#container2").hide();
    });
};
```

This seams right to a newb like me, Can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong?

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bundaberg/S8h5v/)

thanks

Comment: I know you want to keep things simple, this is just in case you want to add more tabs (this way you won't have to copy the code n times) http://jsfiddle.net/S8h5v/2/

Comment: Spokey, this is amazing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial problem here is that you are only binding the click event if the container is visible. You want the bind the event and check the state inside the callback.

```
$("#container1").hide();


$("#link1").click(function () {
    if ($("#container1").is(":visible")) {
        $("#container1").hide();
        $("#container2").show();
    };
});

$("#link2").click(function () {
    if ($("#container2").is(":visible")) {
        $("#container1").show();
        $("#container2").hide();
    };    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S8h5v/1/

It is worth while to talk about why this is happening and why you were expecting a different result. To do that we should walk through the execution stack for each example:

```
hide the container1 element
check if container1 is visible (it isn't) and if so:
  add a callback to the click event of link1 element
check if container2 is visible (it is) and if so:
  add a callback to the click event of link2 element
user clicks link2
  callback registered to link2 click is fired
    show container1
    hide container2
```

now you can see that even if the user clicks link1 there will be no effect because the callback was never registered.

There is a slightly more idiomatic way of approaching this problem which is to create a jquery plugin, something like the following:

```
// http://jsfiddle.net/S8h5v/5/

// js:

$.fn.tabSample = function(){
    $(this).each(function(idx, el){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.delegate('.tabs div', 'click', function(event){
            var index = $this.find(".tabs div").index(event.target);
            $this.find(".contents div").removeClass('active');
            var item = $this.find(".contents div:eq(" + index + ")").addClass('active');
            console.log(item, index);
        });
        $this.find('.contents div:eq(0)').addClass('active');
    });
};

// html

<div class="tab-control">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div>Link 1</div>
    <div>Link 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contents">
    <div>container 1</div>
    <div>container 2</div>
  </div>
</div>

// css

.tab-control .tabs div {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:10px 30px;
  background-color:blue;
  border: solid 1px lightblue;
}
.tab-control .contents div {
    display: none;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
.tab-control .contents div.active {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The reason you might try this approach is it increases the flexibility of your code. For instance to add new content items you can simply add a new div to the tabs element and a new div to the content element, then they will automatically wire up to support the tabbing. You can also change the way that "showing" and "hiding" are done by enhancing the .active css definition so in more modern browsers you could use css3 transitions and animations. Also this allows your code to be portable, so if you have multiple tab controls on a single page you can create them without running into collisions:

```
$(".first-tabset").tabSample();
$(".second-tabset").tabSample();
// any elements within these sets will not affect the other.
```

Comment: Thanks! This had me in knots !

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/BJ8vZ/ solution without jquery, and keyboard arrow keys activated

```
<style>
    #tabs {border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;height:33px;margin:0 0 10px;padding-top:5px;background:#eee;}
    #tabs a {float:left;margin-left:2px;border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;border:1px solid #eee;border-bottom-color:#ccc;color:#08c;height:32px;line-height:32px;padding:0 12px;text-decoration:none;}
    #tabs a:hover {background:#ddd;color:#058;border-color:#ddd #ddd #ccc;}
    #tabs a.active {background:#fff;color:#555;border-color:#ccc #ccc #fff;}
    #tabs a.active:hover {background:#fff;color:#555;border-color:#ccc #ccc #fff;}
    #tabs_data fieldset {display:none;border:0;}
    #tabs_data fieldset div {font-size:13px;}
</style>
<div id="tabs">
    <a href="#" onclick="tab_click(0);">tab 1</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="tab_click(1);">tab 2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="tab_click(2);">tab 3</a>
</div>
<div id="tabs_data">
    <fieldset> contents of tab 1</fieldset>
    <fieldset> contents of tab 2</fieldset>
    <fieldset> contents of tab 3</fieldset>
</div>
<script>
    var tabActive=1, tabs=document.getElementById('tabs').getElementsByTagName('A'), tabs_data=document.getElementById('tabs_data').getElementsByTagName('fieldset');
    function tab_click(x){
        if(x > -1 && x < tabs.length && x < tabs_data.length){
            tabs[tabActive].setAttribute('class','');
            tabs_data[tabActive].style.display='none';
            tabActive=x;
            tabs[tabActive].setAttribute('class','active');
            tabs_data[tabActive].style.display='block';
        } return false;
    }tab_click(0);
    document.onkeydown=function (evnt){ 
        if(evnt.keyCode==37 || evnt.keyCode==39) 
        tab_click(tabActive+evnt.keyCode-38); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I like this - simple and real plain JS.
Although, setAttribute 'class' doesn't work well in IE.  Instead I had to use tabs[tabActive].className = 'active';